# Ionic app freeze on first screen in the iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3

My ionic app is getting freeze in the first screen of the app in iOS device or simulator of Xcode. I am not getting any kind of log or error message from Xcode. Below is my ionic project info
li packages: (/Users/ellyn_philip/Documents/mykidzworld/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.5
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.11.1
npm   : 6.1.0
OS    : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```